# heart rate vs pulse strength when exercising

Tags: exercise

I have noticed, depending on the exercise I am doing, two different patterns (and probably every combination in between):

- if I do an exercise like biking, I can feel I have a faster heart rate but the pulse (touching my neck) doesn't feel very strong.
- in opposite, I have noticed that if I do an exercise like push-ups, the heart rate is not as high, but the pulse feels stronger.

why the difference?

Comment: Get a portable BP  tester, they are inexpensive and accurate ( those I have used).

Comment: I used to have one, but I don't see the link as to why some exercises seem to favor a high heart rate and others seems to elicit a stronger pulse.

Comment: Position matters. You are sitting upright when cycling, but are horizontal with pushups, affecting the way the blood volume moves. Also, when cycling, no Valsalva maneuvers are done, whereas with pushups, weightlifting, etc., people tend to do Valsalvas, which makes the blood volume 'stuck in your neck', so to speak, larger, so the pulse "pressure" will seem greater. Other factors also apply, and it depends when you check your pulse for "pressure".